# "Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdaptorConfiguration" results in ERROR: invalid class

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am currently trying to use powershell to GET the DNS configuration from the NIC of my local computer. My intention is to eventually adapt the command to then modify these settings, then adapt it *further* to target other computers on my network, to standardize the client DNS settings.

I am running PowerShell V2 on windows 7.

So far, my research shows that this is the command to pull the WMI object, which should hold this information:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdaptorConfiguration
```

When executing this command, I get the following output:

```
Get-WmiObject : Invalid class 
At line:1 char:14
+ Get-WMIObject <<<<  Win32_NetworkAdaptorConfiguration
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

So, I am confused as to why it returns "Invalid Class." I have investigated the possibility that WMI may be disabled, by trying to GET another class:

```
Get-WMIObject win32_operatingsystem
```

This correctly returns the details of my OS.

I have also followed a suggestion I found that my WMI Database may be corrupted, but I executed the following:

```
winmgmt /verifyrepository
```

And this returned "WMI repository is consistent"

At this point I am struggling to get any other insight into what could cause this error message. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spelling error is all. `adaptor` should be `adapter`

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
```

Comment: d'oh! I knew it was going to be something frustratingly simple. thanks for being a second (third actually) set of eyes!